# restsharp 107.3.0.0 different signatures with different visual studio versions

Tags: visual-studio-2017, restsharp, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to build using restsharp version 107.3.0.0, the left screen is visual studio 2022 and the right screen is visual studio 2017.

The assembly version is the same in both, however visual studio 2017 is only showing some of the properties.

anyone have any idea why this is?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a known bug because of the Record type, it is supposed to be fixed in the next release.